# SqlAlchemy chaining session.execute not working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am scraping some data and loading them into my database.
To do so, within the same session, I am creating a series of statements (`stmt = select(smthg).where(condition)`) which I execute in the session (`session.execute(stmt)`).

It seems that after I reach a certain number of execution, an error arrise : `ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list`

```
# I create here a set of variables that will then be reused.
# Not detailed for clarity

engine = create_engine("smthg")
With Session(engine) as session : 
    stmt_car = select(model.Cars).where(model.Cars.someparam == somevalue)
    current_car = session.execute(stmt).scalar_one_or_none()
    
    if current_car != None :
        stmt_engine = select(model.Engines).where(model.Engines.type == sometype) 
        db_engine = session.execute(stmt_engine).scalar_one_or_none()
        if db_engine == None:
            #do smthg to create an engine

        stmt_mileage = select(model.Mileages).where(model.Mileages.value == somevalue)
        db_mileage = session.execute(stmt_mileage).scalar_one_or_none()
        if db_mileage == None:
            #do smthg to create the mileage

        # similar tests are performed to create model.Gearboxes, model.Options, ....
        # all-in until that point I reach 8 db_smthg

        stmt_bookings = select(models.Bookings).where(somecondition)
        db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_bookings).scalar_one_or_none()
```

At this point, the `db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_bookings).scalar_one_or_none()` triggers the error.
I tried to recycle my variables (i.e. using an old `stmt_smthg` and an old `db_smthg`) but the error keeps poping.
I thought it may come from my syntax so I tried executing again an old statement, but the error pops again.

Ultimately, if I remove any old statement (i.e. comment a complete piece of logic that was using a `statement` / `session.execute` so that I lower the total count of different `session.execute` I am calling) then I can properly execute the last one.

From this I understand that I reach some kind of internal limitation of SQL Alchemy regarding using multiple `statement` / `session.execute`, which leads to the second conclusion that what I am doing isn't a good practice.
Note that I was using this approach in order to delay as much as possible the `session.commit()` command in order to lower the number of requests to the underlying database.
Am I correctly understanding the issue ? If so what would be the proper way of executing a series of queries to the database and updating only once everything's done ? Else, what to update ?

The complete error message is

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 198, in parse_cars_details
db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_bookings).scalar_one_or_none()
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 33, in run
self.parse_cars_details(response)
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 300, in <module>
t.run()
```

And the complete traceback is :

```
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 303, in <module>
t.run()
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 35, in run
self.parse_cars_details(response)
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 200, in parse_cars_details
db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_bookings).scalar_one_or_none()
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1660, in execute
util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 460, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1086, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1117, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1234, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1256, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 2023, in pymssql._mssql._substitute_params
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 2000, in pymssql._mssql._quote_data
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1976, in pymssql._mssql._quote_or_flatten
ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
```

I tried changing my conditions that uses the Python `&` operator in order to use the `and_` method from SQL Alchemy, meaning that `select(model.Bookings).where((model.Bookings.car_id == id) & (model.Bookings.date == current_date))` becomes `select(model.Bookings).where(and_(model.Bookings.car_id == id, model.Bookings.date == current_date))`
I still got the same error with a different traceback but still the same error within the SQL Alchemy script :

```
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 303, in <module>
t.run()
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 35, in run
self.parse_cars_details(response)
File "[removed]\tester.py", line 200, in parse_cars_details
db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_booking).scalar_one_or_none()
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1660, in execute
) = compile_state_cls.orm_pre_session_exec(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\context.py", line 316, in orm_pre_session_exec
session._autoflush()
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2246, in _autoflush
self.flush()
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3383, in flush
self._flush(objects)
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3522, in _flush
with util.safe_reraise():
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
compat.raise_(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 3483, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
rec.execute(self)
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 630, in execute
util.preloaded.orm_persistence.save_obj(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
_emit_insert_statements(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\persistence.py", line 1238, in _emit_insert_statements
result = connection._execute_20(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
ret = self._execute_context(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
self._handle_dbapi_exception(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2128, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 208, in raise_
raise exception
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
self.dialect.do_execute(
File "[removed]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 732, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
File "src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx", line 460, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1086, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1117, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1234, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1256, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 2023, in pymssql._mssql._substitute_params
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 2000, in pymssql._mssql._quote_data
File "src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx", line 1976, in pymssql._mssql._quote_or_flatten
ValueError: expected a simple type, a tuple or a list
```

Comment: What is `somecondition`? What does `print(somecondition)` show?  What about `print(repr(somecondition))`?

Comment: Whichever valid condition you can imagine. As explained, the statement itself do not cause any issue as long as the total number of statements that were executed with session.execute is below a certain threshold. Any previously working statement will start raising the error, and less statements will allow the last one to be executed properly

Comment: There's no limit on calls to `session.execute`.  The error message tells us that something is being passed an object of an unexpected type.  Please provide a [mre] and a _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: I won't be able to produce a complete code example. What I can say is that I am only using very simple conditions such as `model.Cars.id == id` or `(model.Bookings.car_id == id) & (model.Booking.date == current_date)`, that all the statements are `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select` objects, that a previously working statement stop working at some point. I will include the traceback in the initial message

Comment: The traceback tells us that executing the `stmt_bookings` query raises the error, which means that `somecondition` is the problem.

Comment: it is not coming from somecondition as I manage to make it works when removing the previous statement. Though I did not thought that it can come from the previous statement but due to additional tests, it may be because of it. I did not saw it but the previous statement while not bugging prints the following warning : `SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "rentals" and FROM element "car_options".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.` I do not understand why as both tables are unrelated. I'll include the model declaration in the initial message

Comment: So in the end I identified two typos in the previous statement / block of code (`stmt_rental`). One in the condition which triggered the warning, but wasn't enough to solve the issue. An other one when creating a new line in the table (db_rental = model.Rentals(count = count, car = current_car, asof = date.today)' instead of date.today(). 
What was misleading is that it did not generate any error there and only later if I tried to execute any other request on the database. Any idea why the error do not occur where it should ?

Comment: Broadly speaking, nothing happens with the input values until the session is flushed, at which point the underlying DB-API connector will try to combine them with the SQL statement constructed by SQLAlchemy and send them to the database.  So you see the error when `execute` is called because the session is flushed at that point.

Comment: I'll keep this in mind for next time: the error can be anywhere in between two `execute` call, and not necessarily in the statement of the current `execute` despite the error message.
Thanks for the help & knwoledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to snackecharmerb I manage to understand the issue. While the error message pinpointed to an anomaly while executing the here under statement

```
stmt_bookings = select(models.Bookings).where(somecondition)
db_bookings = session.execute(stmt_bookings).scalar_one_or_none()
```

the actual issue was a bit more complex. To quote snackecharmerb :

> nothing happens with the input values until the session is flushed, at which point the underlying DB-API connector will try to combine them with the SQL statement constructed by SQLAlchemy and send them to the database. So you see the error when execute is called because the session is flushed at that point.

Meaning that anything in between the last session.execute and the current one, can trigger an exception which will be referenced only as coming from `session.execute`.

In my case, it was a typo in a piece of code I did not provide (i.e. `()` lacking after `date.today`) leading to allocate a `builtin_function_or_method` instead of a `datetime.date` within a Table's field.

But as the allocation only happens when the session is flushed, the issue was raised at a later stage, and mislead me into thinking it was coming from something else.